# Infinite decimal expansions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the real numbers contained in the interval $(5,6)$ and having a decimal expansion with only $4$s and $7$s to the right of the decimal point. How would I prove that there are uncountably many such numbers?

Comment: Every number in the interval $(5,6)$ has a decimal expansion starting with $5$.  There are none that contain only $4$'s and $7$'s.  Or did you mean that after the initial $5$ there are only $4$'s and $7$'s?

Comment: Besides which... $c$ is a single decimal expansion.  What do you mean for a single decimal expansion to be uncountable?  Do you mean the *set of all $c$* such that $c$'s decimal expansion (*after the decimal point*) consist of only $4$'s and $7$'s... that the *set of all such $c$* is uncountable?

Comment: Once you correct your problem statement... compare this to the problem of asking about the cardinality of the power set of $\Bbb N$

Comment: Perhaps OP means $c$ is the set of all reals (in $(5,6)$ of course) with only 4s and 7s in their decimal expansions?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor yes sorry that’s what I meant, the first digit is between 5 and 6, but the decimal expansion consists of only 4s and 7s

Comment: How would I go about proving this without comparing to the cardinality of the power set of N? Is there a simpler way

Comment: See [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument#Uncountable_set) -- just replace the $0$s and $1$s with $4$s and $7$s.

Comment: @r.e.s. I’ve only ever seen Cantor’s diagonal argument in reference to proving that (0,1) is uncountable, but sure that isn’t just restricted to 0s and 1s right to the decimal point, could you explain it to me?

Comment: @user794682 repeat the same argument for numbers if they were written in binary.  That said... I don't know why you were so dismissive about comparing to the cardinality of the power set of $\Bbb N$...  that seems the *easiest* to do here.  Just look at the positions of the $4$'s and the positions of the $7$'s.  Form the obvious bijection from such a sequence of digits to a subset of $\Bbb N$ by having the subset simply be "*the indices of the positions occupied by $7$'s*".   So... $5.44444444\dots$ where all are $4$'s corresponds to the empty set while $5.747444\dots$ corresponds to $\{1,3\}$

Comment: There is the huge advantage to this in that this is actually going to be a bijection.  If you were to try to use the same argument for the numbers written in binary, you run into issues where the function is not well defined or is not surjective if you account for that... you have both $0.1010111\overline{1}_2\dots$ is in fact equal as a number to $0.101100\overline{0}_2\dots$ despite wanting to map to different sets  (*see $0.99999\dots = 1$*) but here there is no danger of that since $0.747477\overline{7}$ is not actually equal to $0.7477\overline{4}$